# To hide "..." used in the will_paginate function on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using will_paginate due to the volume of values, but I can't figure out how to hide the "..." portion and the page numbers after. This is what I currently have:
[image]

This is what I'd like to have:

< 1 2 3 4 >
clicking next would give me
< 2 3 4 5 >
(Notice how in both, we don't see the ".." followed by 95 96 97.)

Any idea how this can be done?
Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="pagination full">
  <span class="previous_page disabled">&lt; 前へ</span>
  <em class="current">1</em>
  <a rel="next" href="/student/search?page=2">2</a>
  <a href="/student/search?page=3">3</a>
  <a href="/student/search?page=4">4</a>
  <a href="/student/search?page=5">5</a>
  <a href="/student/search?page=6">6</a>
  <a href="/student/search?page=7">7</a>
  <a href="/student/search?page=8">8</a>
  <a href="/student/search?page=9">9</a>
  <span class="gap">…</span>
  <a href="/student/search?page=95">95</a>
  <a href="/student/search?page=96">96</a>
  <a href="/student/search?page=97">97</a>
  <a class="next_page" rel="next" href="/student/search?page=2">次へ &gt;</a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: So when on page 1, you want three numbers after the current page, but on page 2 you want one number before and two after?

Comment: @JordanRunning I basically want to show only hrefs in a window of four. So if the user is currently on page one, I want it to show <previous> 1 2 3 4 <next>. If we go to page 2, it should shift everything by one. Thus, we will get <previous> 2 3 4 5 <next>. Unfortunately, currently it will be <pevious> 2 3 4 5 6 7 .... 96 97 <next>. I just want to remove that extra part ( 6 7 ... 96 97)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a custom renderer for `will_paginate`. The `will_paginate` helper accept a parameter `renderer` like this:

```
<%= will_paginate(@users, :renderer => UserPaginationRenderer) %>
```

You just need to implement the `UserPaginationRenderer` yourself, with your own rules, like showing only 4 links and so on. There is plenty of information and articles about this:

https://thewebfellas.com/blog/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate
https://www.tachyonstemplates.com/2017/custom-renderer-will-paginate/